# How do I center text using animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate text alignment to the center of a block by a condition in CSS and keep the alignment style after resizing the window. Could anyone suggest a solution?

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

.outer {
  text-align: right;
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .outer {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  .inner {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
}

nav {
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #0073BE;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Text 1</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: could you elaborate the question more clearly

Comment: I tried to formulate my question differently for you.

Comment: as from my understanding , u need an animation to move text to center with  a duration